# How to have programs automatically added to dash and updated?

Tags: apt, updates, unity-dash

Some of the programs I use, like terminal programs, haven't been updated in years, so I am comfortable installing them with `sudo apt install`.

However, a great many programs, like Arduino, Stellarium, Inkscape, Steam, Kdenlive, etc. are updated frequently - if you install them from the Ubuntu software center or using `sudo apt install`, you get an ancient version. So I download the programs manually, often as an `.AppImage` file; this is actually often the recommended way.

This approach has two problems: 1. Programs aren't added to Dash, so I *have* to launch them from terminal *or* manually create `.local/share/applications/*.desktop` files; 2. Updating the programs is a manual process, and quite involved, if I also want to update the `.local/share/applications/*.desktop` files.

Is there a smart way to *both* have my programs update automatically *and* have them accessible from dash?

Comment: Your description of the issues seems accurate and well-researched. Seems like you already answered your own question: You must write your own .desktop files and you must script your own updates for AppImages. If you manage to automate either process reliably, please contribute your code to Debian so it merges into Ubuntu.